# function delete_item() from array php

Tags: php, arrays, function, element

Why this function does not work? After calling it, the same array is printed.

```
$myArray1 = ["Barcelona",  "Romania", "Cile", "France"];

function del(&$array, $item_to_del){
    foreach ($array as $item) {
        if ($item == $item_to_del){
            unset($item);

        }
    }
}

del($myArray1, "Barcelona");
var_dump($myArray1);
```

Comment: Because you're not actually deleting the item in the array. You're unsetting `$item`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must delete the `index` also.

Try this:

```
<?php

$myArray1 = ["Barcelona",  "Romania", "Cile", "France"];

function del(&$array, $item_to_del){
    foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
        if ($item == $item_to_del){
            unset($array[$key]);

        }
    }
}

del($myArray1, "Barcelona");
var_dump($myArray1);
```

Comment: Md Mahfuzur Rahman,
thank you, that works, cool. But it is weird since it is not a map.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace your del function with this. try this:

```
function del(&$array, $item_to_del){
    if (($key = array_search($item_to_del, $array)) !== false) {
        unset($array[$key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What will happen if the item repeats multiple time into the array ?